# Using Laravel 5 Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a model using

```
php artisan make:model Sessions
```

which creates a model named Sessions in the App\ folder. My Model (Sessions) and the controller(School) calling the model are below

Model (Sessions):

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sessions extends Model {

    //
    protected $table = "sch_sessions";
    protected $primaryKey  = "session_id";

}
```

Controller (School)

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App;

class SchoolController extends Controller {
    public function sessionManagement(){        
        $Sessions = Sessions::all();
    }   
}
```

I get the following error

> FatalErrorException in SchoolController.php line 7: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found

I've tried putting the model in a folder and "use"ing it but nada. I'm stumped as to why the error is referring to a controller in the first place. Can anyone see something I don't (can't) please?

Comment: Adding `use Session;` under `use App;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add on the top

```
use App\Sessions;
```

or use it with prefix

```
\App\Sessions::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

If user Ali Mohammed's answer doesn't clear it up for you, it looks to me like your error is happening elsewhere.  `App\Http\Controllers\Session` note `Session` is not plural.

Are you attempting to use the `Session` class elsewhere in your controller?  If so, make sure to prefix it so it's using the `Session` declared in the global namespace.  You can do this with `\Session`.